# exception while check wifi availability

Tags: android, android-wifi, network-state

i have this code for chech if wifi connection is available, called before an asyncTask, and after my device detect a nfc tag:

```
public static boolean connectionAvailable(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    Log.i("UTILS", connManager.toString());

    NetworkInfo mWifi = connManager
            .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

    Log.i("UTILS", mWifi.toString());

    return mWifi.isConnected();
}
```

now i get this error:

```
05-26 12:20:14.157: E/InputEventReceiver(19847): Exception dispatching input event.
05-26 12:20:14.157: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19847): Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
05-26 12:20:14.167: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19847): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-26 12:20:14.167: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19847):  at com.example.Utils.connectionAvailable(Utils.java:14)
05-26 12:20:14.167: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19847):  at com.example.fragments.CustomerSummary.completeRequest(CustomerSummary.java:124)
05-26 12:20:14.167: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19847):  at com.example.SignInActivity.onTouch(SignInActivity.java:232)
05-26 12:20:14.167: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19847):  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7701)
05-26 12:20:14.167: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19847):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
05-26 12:20:14.167: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19847):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
05-26 12:20:14.167: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19847):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
05-26 12:20:14.167: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19847):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
05-26 12:20:14.167: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19847):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
05-26 12:20:14.167: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19847):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
05-26 12:20:14.167: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19847):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
05-26 12:20:14.167: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19847):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
05-26 12:20:14.167: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19847):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2068)
05-26 12:20:14.167: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19847):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1515)
05-26 12:20:14.167: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19847):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2458)
05-26 12:20:14.167: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19847):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2016)
05-26 12:20:14.167: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19847):  at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7886)
05-26 12:20:14.167: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19847):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3954)
05-26 12:20:14.167: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19847):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3833)
05-26 12:20:14.167: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19847):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3399)
05-26 12:20:14.167: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19847):  at  android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
05-26 12:20:14.167: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19847):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3418)
05-26 12:20:14.167: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19847):  at  android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3525)
05-26 12:20:14.167: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19847):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3426)
05-26 12:20:14.167: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19847):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3582)
05-26 12:20:14.167: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19847):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3399)
05-26 12:20:14.167: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19847):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
05-26 12:20:14.167: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19847):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3418)
05-26 12:20:14.167: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19847):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3426)
05-26 12:20:14.167: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19847):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3399)
05-26 12:20:14.167: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19847):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5602)
05-26 12:20:14.167: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19847):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5582)
05-26 12:20:14.167: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19847):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5553)
05-26 12:20:14.167: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19847):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5682)
05-26 12:20:14.167: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19847):  at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
05-26 12:20:14.167: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19847):  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
05-26 12:20:14.167: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19847):  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:138)
05-26 12:20:14.167: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19847):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-26 12:20:14.167: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19847):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
05-26 12:20:14.167: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19847):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-26 12:20:14.167: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19847):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-26 12:20:14.167: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19847):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-26 12:20:14.167: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19847):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
05-26 12:20:14.167: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19847):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

where line 14 is this line:

```
.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);w
```

What's wrong?

Comment: your connManager  returning null

Comment: Duh!!! That's a given now, but we need the solution

Comment: Where you called `connectionAvailable(Context context)` from `Fragment` or `Activity`?

Comment: ok, but why? i've got this error after i put my code into a separate class and access it in a static way (before i've that code inside each class that perform a network operation

@SimplePlan i call it from an fragment, but i pass context to class :)

Comment: @giozh issue is about your context. post your code where you called this.

Comment: r u using this code in fragment???if yes then getActivity().getContext() will give you the context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check your context it seems to be null. From the logcat also it seems like this....Once verify the context :)

Answer (score 2):

`context` is `null`. Please check the value you pass to the `connectionAvailable`. If you are using `Activity` as `Context`, it should be running. So, you can use application context instead.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
public static boolean connectionAvailable(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

if (connManager != null) {
    Log.i("UTILS", connManager.toString());
        NetworkInfo mWifi = connManager
                .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
    if (mWifi != null) {
        Log.i("UTILS", mWifi.toString());

        return mWifi.isConnected();
    }
   }
     return false;
 }
```

Comment: But in my case, wifi is turned on and return false is not correct

Comment: Wifi turned on but is it connected to Internet?

Comment: yes. I've solved, context was initialized in a wrong place. Thanks the same :)